# Overload resolution during JSON parsing in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, overloading, typeclass

I am reading "Real World Haskell" (great book) and I have some confusion about how the compiler selects an overloaded function.

If I have a type class

```
type JSONError = String

class JSON a where
    toJValue :: a -> JValue
    fromJValue :: JValue -> Either JSONError a
```

and two instances like these

```
instance JSON Bool where
    toJValue = JBool
    fromJValue (JBool b) = Right b
    fromJValue _ = Left "not a JSON boolean"
```

and

```
instance JSON String where
    toJValue = JString
    fromJValue (JString s) = Right s
    fromJValue _ = Left "not a JSON string"
```

How can the compiler choose between the two "fromJValue" functions, given, for example, an Integer?

Comment: What do you mean by "given an `Integer`"? Can you write a code snippet that shows a situation where you think it would be hard to choose a particular implementation of `fromJValue`?

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe that's part of my confusion. `JBool` and `JString` are members of a data type `JValue` (not shown). I guess that if I created instances for all of the members, then any call to `fromJValue` would resolve to one of the overloaded methods. Then I am not sure how the `Left` versions would ever be called.

Comment: That does seem like part of your confusion. Both implementations of `fromJValue` *do* have clauses for *all* of `JValue`'s constructors -- typeclass dispatch happens based on the _type_ inferred for `fromJValue`, not the _value_ supplied to `fromJValue`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `fromJValue someValue` as part of some expression, Haskell picks the the type that is required by the expression. So if you do for example:

```
case fromJValue someValue of 
    Right str -> putStr str
    Left _ -> error
```

the instance for `JSON String` is chosen because `putStr` takes a string.

In cases where the required type can't be unambiguously determined, you'll get an "ambiguous type variable" error and will have to add a type annotation to manually pick which instance to use.

Note that it's entirely irrelevant which kind of `JValue` `someValue` contains.

Answer (score 1):

In OO languages if you return an object the virtual method table is *returned* along with it. In Haskell if you return a member of type class, the dictionary is *passed in* as a hidden parameter.

So at runtime there is no problem - the hidden dictionary argument is used just like VTable to get the implementation.

Now your question becomes how the compiler chooses the instance initially.

Look at how `fromJValue` is used.

You start with a string containing JSON data and pass it to a parsing function:

```
foo :: String
foo = parseJsonString x
```

Now the compiler knows that it must pass the dictionary of `instance JSON String` along the call chain.

`parseJsonString` (I don't remember the correct name) parses your string to a JSON data type. Something like

```
data ParsedJSON = JBool Bool | JString string | JObject ...

parseJsonString :: JSON a => String -> Either JSONError a
```

First, it tries to convert the passed string into `ParsedJSON` data structure.

Second, it passes the structure and the dictionary it already has to `fromJValue`.

Now if `x` is `"{ foo : 222 }"`, the instance is still for `String`, so `Left` branch will be called and the parser will say "not a JSON string".

Another minor point - in production you should have used `return` and `throwError` from `MonadError` instead of `Left` and `Right` to make your intentions clearer. But I think it's only a tutorial code.